# How to make a neural network generalizes better?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I designed a neural network model with large number of output predicted by softmax function. However, I want categorize all the outputs into 5 outputs without modifying the architecture of other layers. The model performs well in the first case but when I decrease the number of output it loses accuracy and get a bad generalization. My question is : Is there a method to make my model performs well even if there is just 5 outputs ? for example : adding dropout layer before output layer, using other activation function, etc.

Comment: This a community specific question. stackoverflow is for coding problems only. For theoratical and conceptual problems, please refer to stack.ai or datascience stack.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a plain neural network then yeah definitely use the RelU activation function in the hidden layers and add dropout layer for each hidden layer. Also you can normalize you data before feeding them to the network.

Comment: Please do not encourage answers to theoretical questions on stackoverfow.